# Insert into table values from a dictionary in a Postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a dictionary in python that I created from a JSON file. Now, I need to pass its values to insert into a postgresql database.

**dictionary**

```
if(i['trailers']):
    a = [
        {'url': i['images'][0]['url'], 'type': i['images'][0]['type']},
        {'url': i['images'][1]['url'], 'type': i['images'][1]['type']},
        {'url': i['trailers'][0]['url'], 'type': 'Trailer'},
        {'url': i['trailers'][1]['url'], 'type': 'Trailer'},
    ]
else:
    a = [
        {'url': i['images'][0]['url'], 'type': i['images'][0]['type']},
        {'url': i['images'][1]['url'], 'type': i['images'][1]['type']},
    ]
length = len(a)
```

Here, I created the dictionary. If there is anything inside the `trailer` it goes A, else it goes B. In the B case, `trailers` doesn't exists. Then I get the length of the dictionary.

Now, I will try to insert these elements into the table media, that depends on movies. Their relation is movie(1):media(n).

**INSERT INTO media**

```
for x in range(length):
    query = ("""INSERT INTO media VALUES (%s, %s, %(url)s, %(type)s);""")
    data = (media_id, media_movie_id)
    cur.execute(query, data)
    conn.commit()
    media_id += 1
```

Here is what I'm trying to do. Since movie can have many media, I'll create a for to move through all the elements and inserting them in the table. With their id being incremented.

The problem is, I don't know how to do this quiet right in Python, since I always create a query and a data and then `cur.execute` it and the example that I got, was a entire dictionary being used, without any other kind of value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if anyone have this kind of problem, the solution is simple, actually.

I remade my dict in something like this:

```
i['trailers'] = i.get('trailers') or []
dictionary = [{'url': x['url'], 'type': x['type']} for x in i['images'] + i['trailers']]
```

This solution was made by @minboost [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951712/8340062)

Then, for the insertion, is something like that:

```
for i, dic in enumerate(dictionary):
    query = ("""
        INSERT INTO media (id, movie_id, url, type)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);
        """
    )
    data = (media_id, media_movie_id, dictionary[i]['url'], dictionary[i]['type'])
    cur.execute (query, data)
    conn.commit()
```

All working perfectly. :)