# How to check if an object exist in python

Tags: python

I have a script to get data from an URL and transform into a JSON file. I have two items that I'm interested.

This is an example of what they return:

```
"images": [
        {
            "type": "PosterPortrait", 
            "url": "https://ingresso-a.akamaihd.net/img/cinema/cartaz/22454-cartaz.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "PosterHorizontal", 
            "url": "https://ingresso-a.akamaihd.net/img/cinema/cartaz/22454-destaque.jpg"
        }
    ], 

"trailers": [
        {
            "embeddedUrl": "//www.youtube.com/embed/YUBBkz5ZbKY", 
            "type": "Youtube", 
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUBBkz5ZbKY"
        }, 
        {
            "embeddedUrl": "//www.youtube.com/embed/YUBBkz5ZbKY", 
            "type": "Youtube", 
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUBBkz5ZbKY"
        }
    ],
```

I need to get the "url" and "type" from each object to save into a Postgresql database OneToMany - movie(One):media(Many).
The problem is that "trailers" could be empty and I don't need to save it, since there isn't any data.

**code.py**

```
if(i['trailers']):
    a = [
        {'url': i['images'][0]['url'], 'type': i['images'][0]['type']},
        {'url': i['images'][1]['url'], 'type': i['images'][1]['type']},
        {'url': i['trailers'][0]['url'], 'type': 'Trailer'},
        {'url': i['trailers'][1]['url'], 'type': 'Trailer'},
    ] 
else:
    a = [
        {'url': i['images'][0]['url'], 'type': i['images'][0]['type']},
        {'url': i['images'][1]['url'], 'type': i['images'][1]['type']},
    ]
```

Here is my code. I'm trying to check if there's any elements inside of i['trailers']. If so, he'll be stored inside a dictionary.

Someone could help me to check this, please? Thanks!

Comment: Not really following fully, but use `if (i.get('trailers'))`, which won't throw an error on a missing key; it will instead return `None`, which is falsey.

Comment: @roganjosh `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Wut...? :P either you misimplemented my suggestion, you have trampled some built-in or I'm overly tired. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: What is the type of `i` in your case? Is it a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `trailers` returns an empty list, and `images` is always not empty, **you can replace all your code with one line** using a list comprehension:

```
a = [{'url': x['url'], 'type': x['type']} for x in i['images'] + i['trailers']]
```

If `trailers` may be missing or `None` (instead of an empty list), you just add this line before it:

```
i['trailers'] = i.get('trailers') or []
```

Comment: `i['trailers'] = i.get('trailers', [])`

Comment: @roganjosh that won't work because if `trailers` exists but if None, it'll be None.

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: @roganjosh if the payload contained `{'trailers': None}` your way would set it at `None` instead of an empty list.

Comment: What? Have you tested your code vs mine? You're still relying on falsey.

Comment: @roganjosh yes, I've tested it: https://repl.it/@MinChoi1/SO-53951608?language=python3 - you should look at my solution - it requires that `trailers` be a list so it can do a one-line list comprehension.

Comment: I'm still not following. In your other example you just redefine `a`

Comment: I have a feeling that I'm wrong on some point here, but your example doesn't convince me of anything

Comment: You'll get your upvote, if applicable, when I look at it with fresh eyes :P I think I'm too tired to see what's going on here, tagging the question for tomorrow

Comment: @minboost thanks, it's working great. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can user `get` method in the Python dictionary as

`val = i.get('trailers', None)`

This will return `i['trailers']` if it exists else it will return `None`.

You can use this in the if condition.

Comment: The `None` is pointless, that's the default value returned on a failed lookup. You only need the second argument if you want to override the default.

Comment: Yea, you are right. You can use it without None as well.